# Most efficient way to make this website content fit horizontally and only overflow vertically

Tags: css

I am still learning so forgive me if I get any terminology incorrect.

I am trying to work on making items fit on screen the way I want and am trying to play with the developer tools in my browser (chrome) to modify existing webpages.

I found a webpage that requires you to scroll horizontally and vertically when zoomed in.

I would like to view the page in a manner so that no matter how much I zoom in (e.g. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + mousewheel up), it does not require horizontal scrolling.

I thought that adding:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

to the body might fix it but it did not.

[This is the website in question](https://www.allbutforgottenoldies.net/articles/top-songs-by-decade/).

Here is an example from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) that shows the effect I am referring to.

Any and all insight/tips would be appreciated.

Comment: you can solve your probleme with `flexbox`.

Answer (score 0):

The scrollbar is created by `#topmenu_lg`. When you zoom in, the font size of the letters inside the songs indexes table is increased and it exceeds the available body width.

To visualize this with ease, add this CSS to your page:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  #topmenu_lg {
    overflow-x: auto;
    max-width: 90%;
  }
}
```

You'll need to come up with a method of displaying those indexes responsively.

Using `<table>` elements for layout was acceptable... about 30 years ago.